# Keyboard shortcut in Word 2010 not working (creates new document instead)

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010

Microsoft Word 2010 obviously overwrites one of my most important shortcuts with something else that I do not need (nor want).

Concretely: I am used to using the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> in order to assign the paragraphs style *Normal* to any paragraph where the cursor is placed.

I have assignd this shortcut to the paragraph style *Normal* in my Word 2010 as well.

However, whenever I use this shortcut, Word 2010 instead opens a new, empty document.

I have checked, if <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> is, by any accident, given to the `FileNew` command in the shortcut list (File → Options → Customize Ribbon → Keyboard), but there is nothing assigned to `FileNew`.

I am wondering what might be the reason for my <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> not working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found, for my specific case:

Parallely to MS Word, I have a tiny programme running (a tool for Latin-Cyrillic transliteration) that uses the "Alt + t" shortcut (not Alt + t + 1, though). When I shut this off (or assign a different shortcut to my tiny transliteration tool), Word has no problem working with Alt + t + 1.

So, general rule for shortcut malfunction in Word or elsewhere: Check if not another programme in your Windows environment has occupied the shortcut, or part of it.